# Delete duplicates from PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-10

I'm using the following `query` in `PostgreSQL 10` to find dublicate entries:

```
select
  column1, column2, count(*)
from mytable
  where column3 in ('yes', 'no')
group by column1, column2 having count(*) > 2;
```

Is it possible to have `PostgreSQL` delete the dublicates except of course the first of each entry?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your table has a primary key:

```
delete from mytable t
    where t.pk <> (select min(t2.pk)
                   from mytable t2
                   where t2.column1 = t.column1 and
                         t2.column2 = t.column2 and
                         t2.column3 in ('yes', 'no')
                  );
```